# Use XAML path geometries in android

Tags: android, vector-graphics

I have a DrawingImage library (icons) for my Windows application development under WPF. I am new to Android development and this library has a lot of path geometries that I would like to use in my Android projects.

I searched to find a built-in way to use geometries such as "F1 M 0 0 -5.715 5 -8.48 5 -14.195 0 0 0 z m -15.0977 9.0001 0 -1 0 -7.461 5.488 4.803 -4.809 3.206 7.319 5.91 7.324 -5.91 -4.81 -3.206 5.488 -4.803 0 8.461 -7.998 6.795 -8.002 -6.795 z" directly in Android however I could not find a way.

I have run into some libraries that can display SVG images and they are OK. However I need to display my path geometries from XAML in android. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that it is not possible to transfer my XAML vectors into Android environment. I took another way:

As far as I see, the best way to use verctor icons in Android is using font icon libraries. https://github.com/bperin/FontAwesomeAndroid is what I used.

Later I needed more icons than provided by the FontAwesome library. My search ended with http://fontastic.me/ service. You can generate your custom font collection free of charge. Then I modified source code of FontAwesomeAndroid so I am able to use my own font icon collection.